# My appium's second test keeps getting a java null point exception

Tags: java, junit, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am trying to create a framework to test cross-platform mobile web apps (non native). Here is how my code is setup:

Test Class:

```
 public class TestSuite extends MobileLibrary{

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpTests() throws Exception {
        setUp();

    }  

    @AfterClass
    public static void cleanUpTests() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
    }



    @Test
    public void validateSignIn() throws Exception
    {

        String username = "testtest";
        String password = "testtest";
        SignInMobile(driver,username,password);
        assertTrue(true);

    }
    @Test
    public void randomTests() throws Exception

        dbcSelector(driver,"test");
        assertTrue(true);
    }


}
```

Base Class

```
public class SetupBase 
{

    protected static AppiumDriver driver;
    protected static AppiumPlatform appiumPlatform;
    protected static DeviceSize deviceSize;
    protected static DeviceName deviceName;
    protected static String deviceID;
    protected static DesiredCapabilities capabilities;
    protected static enum AppiumPlatform{
        DESKTOP,IOS,ANDROID
    }
    protected static enum DeviceSize{
        SMALL,MEDIUM,LARGE
    }
    protected static enum DeviceName{
        NEXUS7,S5,IPHONE5S
    }
    public static void setUp() throws MalformedURLException /*throws Exception*/ {



    String deviceNameEnv = System.getenv("DEVICENAME");
    switch(deviceNameEnv){
        //sets devicename here
    }
    //sets platform here
    if(deviceName==DeviceName.NEXUS7 || deviceName==DeviceName.S5)
        appiumPlatform = AppiumPlatform.ANDROID;
    else if(deviceName==DeviceName.IPHONE5S)
        appiumPlatform = AppiumPlatform.IOS;
    else
        appiumPlatform = AppiumPlatform.DESKTOP;

    switch(deviceName){     
        //sets size here
    }

    capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName",deviceID);

    if(appiumPlatform==AppiumPlatform.ANDROID){
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("browserName","Chrome");
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    }
    else if(appiumPlatform==AppiumPlatform.IOS){
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName","iOS");
        capabilities.setCapability("browserName","Safari");
        driver  = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    }


    }
}
```

No matter what I do, any time I try to use driver in the second test I will get a java null pointer exception. MobileLibrary extends the baseclass and contains all my WebDriver element functions.
**Edit:** If I directly do driver.findelement in my second test I get an element not found exception. It looks like something is being reset after the end of a @test and I have no idea what.

Comment: Where you have coded "dbcSelector()" & "SignInMobile()" methods? and whats there in  it?

Comment: Mobile library. Its basically a return driver.findelement. It works if I call it in the first test.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the problem was actually with the @test order execution. I didn't realize that junit doesn't run tests in order, I'll be looking into the test suite fixtures.

Comment: Many people consider it a code smell if tests depend on the order. Instead, they should be independent. It is much easier to diagnose a problem if you have to look at only 1 test, not 20.

Comment: If I do it that way, I would have to login to the website, choose something, wait for it to load, change several settings, then finally do the actual test. This would be complicated and time consuming. The way the website is designed I can't simply do a url + text to start where I left off. Do you think there's still a better way?

Comment: Can you login to the website in a @BeforeClass, and keep the other tests independent? Or does one test create a state that the other test uses (e.g., populate a database)?